# How to filter ANY dns requests with tshark

Tags: domain-name-system, pcap, tshark

Does anyone know how I might be able to filter DNS requests in tshark which ask for the ANY record?
So far I am able to filter DNS queries with:
`tshark -r capture.cap -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e dns.qry.name -R "dns.flags.response eq 0"` 
How would I also filter by ANY ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to filter queries where the QTYPE is * (also known as ANY) (represented by the integer 255):

In WireShark or NetMon this would be

```
"dns.qry.type==255"
```

So for `tshark` I assume it would be:

```
"dns.qry.type eq 255"
```

You can find the numerical values for all query types in [RFC 1035 §3.2.3 "QTYPE Values"](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt)